# Node.js: using socket.io with cluster

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, cluster-computing

i want to use socket.io with cluster .
This is what i tried but i got this error :

TypeError: RedisStore is not a constructor

```
const app = express()
const redis = require('redis')
var cluster = require('cluster'),
numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
//master process - fork children
for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork()
}
}
else {
var RedisStore = require('redis')
    , pub = redis.createClient()
    , sub = redis.createClient()
    , client = redis.createClient();

var io = require('socket.io').listen(5000, {
    'store': new RedisStore({
        redisPub: pub
        , redisSub: sub
        , redisClient: client
    }),
});
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // all socket.on('eventname'... things go here
});
const http = require('http')
http.createServer(app).listen(4000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RedisStore` is a functionality added by the `connect-redis` module, not `redis`. to fix that you just need to change `var RedisStore = require('redis')` to `var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')`.

`RedisStore` constructor expects to get an object with the `redis` property, and it should be a redis client ([`connect-redis` API Docs](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis#api)).

Comment: Thanks and does it need to install redis database ?

Comment: @soroushasamiesfahan the `redis` module is a client to work with a [Redis](https://redis.io/) database/server